# Probe with exponential increase then binary search lowest unused in distributed hash table - dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable, binary-search, quadratic-probing

I need advice how to aproach this task. The autor has created function **find_next_free_dataset_num(node)** and it searching for free slots in distributed hash table. This DHT uses dictionary like interface which override **__setitem__**, **__getitem__** and **__contains__**. Which is good 
design. But this function uses linear probing now for searching new unused slot for
predictable key. So the question is if exponential **num = num*num + 1** solves it and
how to implement binary search on new num value between 0 and used slot num?

```
def predictable_key(node, num):
    return "monitor_dataset_{0}_{1}".format(node.get_address(), str(num))


def find_next_free_dataset_num(node):
    # FIXME probe with exponential increase then binary search lowest unused
    num = 0
    while node[predictable_key(node, num)] is not None:
        _log.info("Dataset {0} already exists!".format(num))
        num += 1
    return num
```